# Select the .next() element with a specific attribute JQUERY

Tags: jquery, attributes, jquery-selectors

This is what I have :

```
$("#comment").next().attr('shown',0).fadeIn();
```

I'm trying to show the next comment that is hidden on the page.  however, I'm trying to do two comments shown at a time, so if you click the first one, the second one is next.  So I've given a **shown** attribute.  I would like to select the **NEXT** with the attribute `shown=0`.  The above does not work.  I believe it would be `next(tr[shown=0])` but i can't get that to work (i'm in a table looking for the next row)

any help is appreciated!

Comment: Could it be because 'shown' is not a default attribute in HTML ? Try with an Id , class or name instead.

Answer (score 13):

`next` can only return the immediate next sibling.

You can call `nextAll`, which returns all subsequent siblings, with the `:first` selector to get the first matching one:

```
$(...).nextAll("tr[shown=0]:first")
```

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old post, but just going by the title the first answer threw me off.  However @SLaks answer is exactly what I was looking for personally and fixed my issue.

This actually helped me out a lot in a completely different situation while just happening to find this post.  This answer is the best one as mentioned in his response.

The issue I had was something similar to something below and I had to pick from a specific attribute in order to get the next one with similar attribute name, but different value.

```
<div class="blah" data-field="sometext" data-index="0"></div>
<div class="bar"></div>
<div class="blah" data-field="sometext" data-index="1"></div>


$("div[data-field='sometext'][data-index='0']")
    .nextAll("div[data-field='sometext']:first");
```

Above returns

```
  <div class="blah" data-field="sometext" data-index="1"></div>
```

Hope this helps someone else as it helped me out greatly

Answer (score 1):

SLaks answer will work, but I would consider not using custom attributes in your HTML as it might confuse another developer down the road. Something like this would use no custom attributes:

```
<style>
.hidden {
    display:none;   
}
</style>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){ 
   $('.showmore').click(function(){ 
       $(this).parent().nextAll(':hidden:first').removeClass('hidden');
   })
});
</script>

<div id="comments">
<div class="comment" id="comment1">
    Test comment        
    <a href="#" class="showmore">Show More</a>
</div>
<div class="comment" id="comment2">
    2nd test comment
    <a href="#" class="showmore">Show More</a>
</div>
<div class="comment hidden" id="comment3">
    3rd test comment
</div> 
<div class="comment hidden" id="comment4">
    4th test comment
</div>   
</div>
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tFu29/1/)